# Partial divide two sets of points

Tags: 2d, partial, divide, plane

I have 2 classes of points on a 2D plane. 
I want to visually separate them (with a straight line/s) when drawing a graph on the screen.

In cases where they are not separable with a single straight line i thought the next best thing would be to partially separate them by having two **parallel** lines **l1** and **l2** such that **all points of class A are above l2** (in regards to x-axis) and **all points of class B are bellow l1**. That is easy to do but i need the distance between the 2 lines to be as small as possible. How could i achieve that?

I drew a sketch demonstrating what i am trying to do.
In the sketch the 2 different classes are represented by 2 different colors (black and green).
All green points need to be under line 1 and all black points need to be above line 2, and the distance (d) between the two lines has to be as small as possible.

[image]